# applying basic rules of replacement / inference in proofs of logical equivalence and implication

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm a beginner in proof-based math, and I'm trying to flesh out my understanding of the reasoning behind proofs of logical equivalence ($a \iff b$) and implication ($a \implies b$).

- When proving that some compound proposition, which is made up of various atomic propositional variables (say $p, q, r$), *is equivalent to* another compound proposition, it seems that at each step in a proof to iteratively show logical equivalence we can replace any proposition with an equivalent one. For example, using a known premise that $p \iff q$ in a broader proof of logical equivalence:
  $$
  \begin{align}
       & \dots p \dots \newline
  \iff & \dots q \dots
  \end{align}
  $$

  - Is this indeed true? Is there a specific rule of logic that this technique is appealing to?
- Moreover, when proving that some compound proposition, which is made up of various atomic propositional variables (say $p, q, r$), *implies* some other compound proposition, I've been assuming that we can do the analogous replacement: i.e., that in a proof to iteratively show logical implication we can replace any proposition with one that it implies. For example, using a known premise that $p \implies q$ in a broader proof of logical implication:
  $$
  \begin{align}
           & \dots p \dots \newline
  \implies & \dots q \dots
  \end{align}
  $$

  - Is this valid reasoning? If so, is there a specific rule of logic/inference that this technique is appealing to? (If not, why not? Is there some simple counterexample to help understanding why?)

I've referred to various "intro to proofs" math texts and also looked around the internet, and I can't find any resource stating either of these facts clearly in this context. So any insights or clarification including a pointer to useful references would be very helpful.

Comment: Logical laws and rules are schematic, i.e. every instance of them is a valid formula/inference.

Comment: This means that replacement is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - When proving that some compound proposition, which is made up of various atomic propositional variables (say $p, q, r$), *is equivalent to* another compound proposition, it seems that at each step in a proof to iteratively show logical equivalence we can replace any proposition with an equivalent one. For example, using a known premise that $p \iff q$ in a broader proof of logical equivalence:
>   $$
>   \begin{align}
>        & \dots p \dots \newline
>   \iff & \dots q \dots
>   \end{align}
>   $$
>   Is this indeed true? Is there a specific rule of logic that this technique is appealing to?

Yes, it is true you can make those substitutions/replacements.  It is not so much an equivalence principle like DeMorgan or Distribution, but rather a *meta-logical* principle. It is called the Replacement Theorem ... but it being a meta-logical principle, you don't really need to refer to it.  Thus, going from something like:

$$A \lor \neg \neg B$$

to

$$A \lor B$$

can be justified by Double Negation (even though you implicitly do use the Law of Replacement as well)

> - Moreover, when proving that some compound proposition, which is made up of various atomic propositional variables (say $p, q, r$), *implies* some other compound proposition, I've been assuming that we can do the analogous replacement: i.e., that in a proof to iteratively show logical implication we can replace any proposition with one that it implies. For example, using a known premise that $p \implies q$ in a broader proof of logical implication:
>   $$
>   \begin{align}
>            & \dots p \dots \newline
>   \implies & \dots q \dots
>   \end{align}
>   $$
>   Is this valid reasoning? If so, is there a specific rule of logic/inference that this technique is appealing to? (If not, why not? Is there some simple counterexample to help understanding why?)

No!  This is *not* valid (or rather, not always .. which is why, for safety sake, we never allow it)

Consider:

We know that we have a rule (often called Simplification or $\land$ Elimination) that allows you to go from:

$$P \land Q$$

to:

$$P$$

But note, if you would be allowed to apply this to:

$$(P \land Q) \to R$$

you would get:

$$P \to R$$

and that is *not* a valid inference!  (set P to true and $Q$ and $R$ to False, and $(P \land Q) \to R$ wil be True, but $(P \land Q) \to R$ will be false.

So no, there is no such analogous replacement principle for logical implication like there is for logical equivalence.

Comment: This completely answers both of my questions. Thank you so much! The counterexample for why the second part is not valid is very clear and helpful (and easy to remember why not to do this!)

Comment: My main follow-up question then is on how to proceed for proofs of implication ($a \implies b$). Is the correct way to proceed by *only* appealing to (i) the Law of Replacement to substitute equivalent statements, and (ii) rules of inference (e.g. Modus Ponens), when following steps of iterative implication, as above?

Comment: @xyzo Yes, exactly. You can use any equivalence principles, and apply them to any part of the statement, and you can also use rules of inference, but they can only be applied to whole statements

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this site, and this is a great question:

> - Moreover, when proving that some compound proposition, which is made up of various atomic propositional variables (say $p, q, r$), *implies* some other compound proposition, I've been assuming that we can do the analogous replacement: i.e., that in a proof to iteratively show logical implication we can replace any proposition with one that it implies. For example, using a known premise that $p \implies q$ in a broader proof of logical implication:
>   $$
>   \begin{align}
>            & \dots p \dots \newline
>   \implies & \dots q \dots
>   \end{align}
>   $$

If

- (compound) proposition $p$ logically implies (compound) proposition $q,$ and
- proposition $A$ is obtained from $p$ by finitely many applications of the connectives and/or quantifiers, and
- proposition $B$ is obtained by substituting all instances of $p$ in $A$ with $q,$

then $A$ **does not** logically imply $B.$

For example, \begin{align}p&:=\alpha\land\beta\\q&:=\alpha\\A&:= (\alpha\land\beta)\to\gamma\\B&:=\alpha\to\gamma.\end{align}

(On the other hand, if $p\equiv q$ instead, then $A$ does logically imply $B.$ This substitution process appeals to one of the [replacement rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement).)

Comment: Thank you! The link on replacement rules was especially useful for some added context.

Comment: @xyzo You're welcome! BTW, I hope you noticed the small mistake which I was indirectly pointing out: $p$ and $q$ are general propositions, not both atomic.

Comment: Ah, that's a very good correction. Good point! I now see how it extends for general propositions. Thanks!

Comment: @xyzo I wasn't generalising, but correcting: as pointed out in my comment, $p$ and $q$ can't both be atomic.

Comment: Ah, OK I see now. Your example with compound $p$ makes this clear too. Thank you for clarifying my understanding!