# Conditionals, Biconditionals, and Logical Equivalences in Proof

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was practicing some proofs of basic set theorems (e.g. $ a \notin A-B\; \wedge \; a \in A \Rightarrow a \in B $) and had some questions about proofwriting mechanisms (I have little experience with mathematical logic). If, within some intermediate sentence (say, $\gamma$) of a proof, there is a component sentence $A$ which is related to another sentence $B$ by implication $A \Rightarrow B$, can I simply replace $A$ by $B$ in $\gamma$ to yield a valid sentence? For instance, can I have $ \neg (a \in A - B) \wedge a \in A $ be replaced by $\neg(a \in A \wedge a \notin B) \wedge a \in A$ in a proof? Also, am I allowed to simply replace sentences in a proof with other sentences which are logically equivalent ($\equiv$) to the original? If these are valid methods, why are they justified logically (please point me to relevant metatheorems)? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Do you mean, e.g. $a\notin (A-B) \land (a\in A\Rightarrow a\in B)$? Or $(a\notin (A-B) \land a\in A)\Rightarrow (a\in B)?$

Comment: This question was just asked a few days ago: [applying basic rules of replacement / inference in proofs of logical equivalence and implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4410252/21813).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only replace sentence A with B if there is a rule of replacement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement) for them and they are complex sentences/propositions (not simple sentences/propositions)

If given/established A⇒B, you can conclude A (not replace anything with it), if also you have established or were given as a premise A.  This is the rule of inference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) modus ponens (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

Rules of inference (excluding the rules of replacement) only go one direction in terms of premises and conclusion, while with rules of replacement you can switch the singular premise with the conclusion and have them reversed and still use it validly, and thus each direction of a rule of replacement is a rule of inference.